NU5000 Error Retrieving Package metadata for 'System.Runtime.4.3.0'
I was trying to restore package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer version 8.0.4 and it hasn't been successful. After many permutations, I kept getting the following error:

NU5000 An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'System.Runtime.4.3.0' from source 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'

Please, how do I go fwd from here?
Installing via NuGet UI, NuGet Console then I tried running Visual Studio with administrator privileges, yet it's the same error message.
I'm targeting .NET 8.0

what version of .net core are you targeting?


I uninstalled System.Runtime by running:
PM> Uninstall-Package System.Runtime -Force

Changed the version of the package failing to install to this:


ProjectReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.3"

Run:

PM> Install-Package System.Runtime

I unloaded the project affected, and reloaded by right-clicking the project node and selecting "Load project with dependencies" and everything is ok now.

Although I still feel I probably didn't need to install System.Runtime package, but I saw that there was references to the SqlServer package while installing the System.Runtime package and since I didn't specify its version and it installed the version the error message indicated, it might not be unconnected. I'm happy everything is alright now, or so it seems.
Thanks to everyone who showed interest. In most cases, it's helpful to know that someone is listening.
Please, note that "PM>" is the prompt for Package Manager Console and shouldn't be typed.
Thanks.
